# Is there a way to make the iPadOS scrollbar permanently visible across apps?

Tags: ios, mouse, ipados, macos

See the title. I’m using a mouse<sup>1</sup> with my iPad (as of iOS 13.4). The lack of persistently visible scroll bars<sup>2</sup> across apps (e.g. in Notes) is reducing my productivity, as I have to do a [pointless](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/127983/62525) scroll wheel manoeuver to make it appear (exacerbated by the fact that the hidden scrollbars do not become visible when touching the right hand margin).

So e.g. is there a setting like on the Mac to make the scrollbar always visible?

<sup>1:  Not an Apple Magic mouse, but various mice with scroll wheels</sup> 
<sup>2:  Including the standard, dedicated margin above & below the scrollbar acting as a page up & down hit target</sup>

Comment: You should consider sharing a feedback with Apple: https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/welcome

Comment: @NimeshNeema good suggestion, submitted now :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of iOS 13.4, the answer is no.